# Write a program to receive 10-12 long types of data

Tags: java

My programming is not good. I try to use for command but i can't do this. Please help me for this program.

Write a program to receive 10-12 long types of data to send the results in the form of numbers using the mark, as a segment. Start at the right side and have 3 numbers per group to the screen.

Sorry for my english i'm from thailand and i use google translate.
this try code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter number1: ");
    long a=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number2: ");
    long b=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number3: ");
    long c=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number4: ");
    long d=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number5: ");
    long e=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number6: ");
    long f=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number7: ");
    long g=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number8: ");
    long h=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number9: ");
    long i=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number10: ");
    long j=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number11: ");
    long k=kb.nextLong();
    System.out.println("enter number12: ");
    long l=kb.nextLong();

    for(long ii=0;ii<=12;ii++) { System.out.printf("%d ",a+i); System.out.printf("%d ",b+i); System.out.printf("%d ",c+i); System.out.printf(",");}
}
```

}
how i can use my code for other digit in 1 for command?

Comment: What do you mean by 10-12 long type ? 10-12 digits ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Post your code please.

Comment: Also, please try to enhance the quality of the translation. The current text cannot be understood. Maybe adding an example makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm guessing the requirement should read something like "write a program that takes as input integers with 10-12 digits and prints the numbers, right justified, with comma separators every 3 digits".

Comment: 12 digit of long type

Comment: Have a read about loops, arrays and lists. It'll save you having to write 12 pairs of lines that differ only in number and variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        long[] arr = getNumbers(12, scan);
        print(arr);
    }
}

public static long[] getNumbers(int total, Scanner scan) throws IOException {
    long[] arr = new long[total];

    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter number " + i + ": ");
        arr[i - 1] = scan.nextLong();
    }

    return arr;
}

public static void print(long[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```